# maxlength on input field wordpress customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, input, wordpress-theming, customizer

Is it possible to put a maxlength on the input fields i use in the customizer.

Like putting some extra setting in the array : maxlength = > 50;

via :

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'textblock-text-content', array(
            'label'      => 'Tekstblok tekst',
            'section'   => 'textblock_background_section',
            'type'   => 'textarea',
        ));
```

I couldnt find any solution, i hope anybody here can guide me to a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Accoding to [Customizer Objects docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#controls), you could use the `input_attrs` parameter like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control('textblock-text-content', array(
    'label' => 'Tekstblok tekst',
    'section' => 'textblock_background_section',
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'input_attrs' => array(
        'maxlength' => 20
    )
));
```

Comment: @Flierp did this answer your question?